# How can i insert multiple data on same mutation in Laravel Lighthouse?

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

Can i insert multi on same mutation?

**I wonder this is exist or not.**

This is my Schema

```
type Test {
    id: ID
    name: String
    msg: String
}

input testInput {
    name: String
    msg: String
}

type Mutation {
    createTest(input: [testInput]): [Test] @create
}
```

This is my mutation query

```
mutation{
    createTest(input: [
        {id:1,  name: "test", msg:"hahaha",},
        {id:2, name: "test2", msg:"hahahaa" }
    ]) {
        id
        name
        msg
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom mutation:

```
php artisan lighthouse:mutation CreateTest
```

If you want something reusable, you might want to implement a custom field resolver directive. Look into the implementation of `@create` for an idea on how that can be done.

Comment: I looked into into the implementation of @create. And i solved it ! Thanks!

Comment: please could you provide an example @JeongkukSeo